# Recipient.Address return incorrect data

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

If I take user from contacts (in addon for outlook) and do this:

```
Outlook.Recipient recipient = c.GetMember(i);
AplicationLog(recipient.Address);
```

It will return this:

```
/0=:someData:/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (:someData:)/cn=Recipients/cn=:curentUserName:eed
```

It add "eed" to user name. And only for one.

Why it do that? How can I fix that?

P.S. I don't do anything with that data before it will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a perfectly valid EX (as opposed to SMTP) address.
If `AddressEntry.Type` is "SMTP", just use `AddressEntry.Address`. If Type == "EX", use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`. AddressEntry object is returned by the `Recipient.AddressEntry` property.